# Attempting to configure storage for Ubuntu Server installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have tried to install Ubuntu probably half a dozen times now. The first few times was trying to get the right iso image and all of that. I'm currently at the step where I partitioned plenty of free space in the Windows native application to shrink volume. I never created a simple volume, and left it as free space. I thought that Ubuntu would do this for me. I'm currently in the installer and it wants me to choose:

- Use an entire disk
- Custom Storage Layout

Inside of the second option, there's options for:

- (Long string of characters)

  - partition 1
  - partition 2
  - (grayed out) free space

I assume that I need to choose the free space option, but it won't let me... What should I do?

EDIT:
If there's no way to select free space and do it from inside of the Installer, do I need to exit the installation (and how would I do that?) and use the windows thing again to make a new simple volume or whatever?

Comment: If you're seeing "Custom Storage Layout", it sounds like you're installing Ubuntu Server. Do you want to install the server version, or the desktop version? The desktop version will detect Windows 10 and give you the option to "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10"

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 and I am installing the server version. I plan on using this as a test environment or a host of sorts.

Comment: Ubuntu Server isn't really designed to be on again off again. I wonder if it would be better to install the system in a virtual machine (using something like VirtualBox) so that you can use both your Windows and Ubuntu Server installations at the same time (depending on system resources, of course) 

Comment: @Matigo This is an old desktop, I don't really plan on turning it on and off to go back to windows. I plan on having this on most of the time. I only want Windows still on my old desktop incase anything goes wrong or if I want to sell the computer.

Comment: Let me clarify. I have another computer and a laptop which I use quite frequently. I plan on using this old desktop (which I haven't found a use for) with Ubuntu Server to do what I said above :)